# Paypal IPN not returning VERIFIED

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to get IPN from PayPal to work, but it keeps returning `INVALID` instead of `VERIFIED` and I can't see what I've done wrong.

At the moment, I have 2 php files using the sample code from paypal's developer site.  The code seem to run fine, I am using the `sandbox` so I can see the payment being transfered, so I don't understand why I am getting `INVALID`.

Can someone have a look at the code as I can't see what I've done wrong.

**1. basic_payment.php (the file which sends the payment data to paypal)**

> ```
> <?php
>   require_once ("paypalplatform.php");
>
>   $actionType = "PAY";
>   $cancelUrl = "http://[my server details go here]/cancel.php";
>   $returnUrl = "http://[my server details go here]/success.php";  
>   $currencyCode = "GBP";
>   $receiverEmailArray = array( 'seller_15456764326_biz@mail.com' );
>   $receiverAmountArray = array( '2' );
>   $receiverPrimaryArray = array();
>   $senderEmail = "";      
>   $feesPayer = "";
>   $ipnNotificationUrl = "http://[my server details go here]/ipn.php";
>   $memo = "";     
>   $pin = "";      
>   $preapprovalKey = "";       
>   $reverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError = "";        
>   $trackingId = generateTrackingID(); 
>   $receiverInvoiceIdArray = array( $trackingId );
>   $resArray = CallPay ($actionType, $cancelUrl, $returnUrl, $currencyCode, $receiverEmailArray,
>                           $receiverAmountArray, $receiverPrimaryArray, $receiverInvoiceIdArray,
>                           $feesPayer, $ipnNotificationUrl, $memo, $pin, $preapprovalKey,
>                           $reverseAllParallelPaymentsOnError, $senderEmail, $trackingId
>   );
>   $ack = strtoupper($resArray["responseEnvelope.ack"]);
>   if($ack=="SUCCESS")
>   {
>       if ("" == $preapprovalKey)
>       {
>           $cmd = "cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=" . urldecode($resArray["payKey"]);
>           RedirectToPayPal ( $cmd );
>       }
>       else
>       {
>           $payKey = urldecode($resArray["payKey"]);
>           $paymentExecStatus = urldecode($resArray["paymentExecStatus"]);
>       }
>   } 
> ?>
> ```

**2. ipn.php (the file which listens for paypals response)**

> ```
> <?php
>
>     $ipn_post_data = $_POST;
>
>     $url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
>
>     $request = curl_init();
>     curl_setopt_array($request, array
>     (
>         CURLOPT_URL => $url,
>         CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
>         CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array('cmd' => '_notify-validate') + $ipn_post_data),
>         CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
>         CURLOPT_HEADER => FALSE,
>     ));
>
>     $response = curl_exec($request);
>     $status   = curl_getinfo($request, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
>
>     curl_close($request);
>
>     $to = "oshirowanen@mail.com";
>     $from = "me@desktop.com";
>     $subject = "response";
>     $message = "<pre>".print_r($status,true)." - ".print_r($response,true)."</pre>\n";
>
>     $header = 'To: Oshirowanen <oshirowanen@mail.com>' . "\r\n";
>     $header .= 'From: Me <me@desktop.com>' . "\r\n";
>
>     mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
>
> ?>
> ```

**The error messages:**

Apache error log - No errors

Which is why I added the email stuff in ipn.php to try to capture something, and it is returning:

`<pre>200 - INVALID</pre>`

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Doesn't the PayPal API have a place where it tells you what it sent to the server? Can we see that data?

Comment: @David, I've added the code you requested.

Comment: I've updated the question to hopefully make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Got it working using the [basic sample code](https://www.paypal-labs.com/integrationwizard/adaptive/paymenttypes.php) 4b,
2. Cleared `$ipnNotificationUrl = "";` from the basic sample code as I had a value in there which I added myself,
3. Created a seller account instead of a business pro account in sandbox,
4. Set the seller account to enable the ipn url,
5. Used the following PHP 5.2 [sample code](https://www.x.com/developers/PayPal/documentation-tools/code-sample/216623) for the ipn listener
6. Added the 2 lines into the listener, as described [here](http://www.geekality.net/2011/05/28/php-tutorial-paypal-instant-payment-notification-ipn/), the 2 lines can be seen below:
7. Downloaded the `cacert.pem` certificate to my server from [here](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) and put it in the same directory as the ipn listener:

The 2 lines mentioned in point 6:

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => TRUE,
CURLOPT_CAINFO => 'cacert.pem',
```

I have no idea why the sandbox business pro account does not let me set an ipn url, but the seller account does.

Answer (score 1):

This caused a confusion at first for me too. 
What you are talking about are 2 different kinds of `IPTN` messages:

1. The first, the one from your question, its url is configured in ipnNotificationUrl, goes to  site that intermediates the transaction. This one cannot be verified by sending the parameters back to Paypal; as you can add parameters yourself to that url, you can implement a `HMAC` mechanism for security.
2. The second, the one from your solution, goes to the account that receives the money, if `IPTN` is enabled in the settings. This one can be verified by sending the parameters back to Paypal.

If you set the same URL for the both messages, you get them both, but just one can be validated using Paypal. If the seller and the site are different entities, in other words if the site just intermediates a transaction between a buyer and a seller, the site receives the first one and the seller the second one.